# Error in dpkg --configure -a and apt install of pepperflash

Tags: dpkg

I have a dell inspiron 14-3467, Ubuntu 18.04. I wanted to install the Opera Browser and the installation was interrupted. It asks me to run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and the machine stays frozen:

```
Setting up pepperflashplugin-nonfree (1.8.3+nmu1ubuntu1).....
```

When I run dpkg --list I get this:

```
iF  pepperflashplugin-nonfree 1.8.3+nmu1ubuntu1 amd64             Pepper Flash Player - browser plugin
```

If I run sudo apt-get install -f it also freezes in:

```
 Setting up pepperflashplugin-nonfree (1.8.3+nmu1ubuntu1).....
```

How can I solve it? Is there a way to eliminate pepperflash or is it necessary to have it?

Comment: It should be asked in ask ubuntu stack exchange. However i simply using `sudo apt remove pepperflashplugin-nonfree`. And this seems common problem with us recently in january 2021. Anybody know what is this flash player doing in my ubuntu 20.10?

Answer (score 1):

```
#remove lock files
rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock

#remove pepperflash
apt remove pepperflashplugin-nonfree

#repair dpkg now success
dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

To see what this package is, use `apt-cache`:

```
apt-cache show pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```

If you deem it unnecessary, remove it:

```
apt purge pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```

Answer (score 0):

> apt-cache show pepperflashplugin-nonfree

```
Package: pepperflashplugin-nonfree
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1.8.3+nmu1ubuntu1
Priority: optional
Section: multiverse/web
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Bart Martens <bartm@debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 31
Pre-Depends: ca-certificates
Depends: debconf | debconf-2.0, wget, gnupg1 | gnupg, libatk1.0-0, libcairo2, libfontconfig1, libfreetype6, libgcc1, libglib2.0-0, libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.14), libnspr4, libnss3, libpango-1.0-0 | libpango1.0-0, libstdc++6, libx11-6, libxext6, libxt6, libcurl3-gnutls, binutils
Suggests: chromium-browser, ttf-mscorefonts-installer, ttf-dejavu, ttf-xfree86-nonfree
Conflicts: chromium-browser (<< 37.0.2062.120-4), libflash-mozplugin
Filename: pool/multiverse/p/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/pepperflashplugin-nonfree_1.8.3+nmu1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
Size: 5536
MD5sum: 47b06fd1cf1d511cc5cf6f7ae979b81b
SHA1: 41636ebbc23d68d2f9c8f72f78a17efd854aac5d
SHA256: 3b21cb1a611d70e1fdc5948c4d4a43c442d71b1f2dc3dac53b5315e90d395347
Homepage: http://wiki.debian.org/PepperFlashPlayer
Description-en: Pepper Flash Player - browser plugin
 This package will download Chrome from Adobe, and unpack it to make the
 included Pepper Flash Player available for use with Chromium.  The end user
 license agreement is available at Adobe.
Description-md5: ffddffcbb66de5d31dd4c784e6aa4973
```

> apt purge pepperflashplugin-nonfree

```
E: Could not lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: The administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) could not be locked, maybe there is some other process using it?
```